# Blank screen while using glGenBuffers in openGL

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void changeSize(int w, int h)
{
    if(h == 0) 
        h = 1;
    float ratio = w / h;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gluPerspective(40,ratio,1.5,20);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void renderScene(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-5.0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void init()
{
    GLfloat verts[] = {
        0.0,   1.0,
       -1.0,  -1.0,
        1.0,  -1.0
    };

    GLuint bufferid;
    glGenBuffers(1,&bufferid);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,bufferid);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(verts),verts,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

    if(glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR)
        printf("no error");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow("MM 2004-05");
    glewInit();

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);

    if (GLEW_ARB_vertex_program && GLEW_ARB_fragment_program)
        printf("Ready for GLSL\n");
    else {
        printf("No GLSL support\n");
        //exit(1);
    }

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

When using glGenBuffers my screen turns out black and shows no error. If i draw some other shape without using buffers they are displayed but not with buffer objects.

openGL version:3.0
operating system:ubuntu
IDE:eclipse

Comment: Where are your shaders?

Comment: there are no shaders its a basic program to draw triangle with buffers

Comment: and there's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `glGenBuffers` you're using the OpenGL-3.0 specification. To draw anything in OpenGL-3.0+ you need to use shaders, hence why the screen is black; your triangle isn't being shaded.

Comment: `glGenBuffers()` was introduced in OpenGL 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You are using calls for generic vertex attributes here:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
```

Generic vertex attributes can only be used in combination with shaders. As long as you're using the fixed function pipeline, you also have to use fixed function vertex attributes.

The corresponding calls using fixed function attributes are:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
```